# How to find out the frame rate of a video?

Tags: opencv, video, video-streaming

How to find out the frame rate of a video ?How to do in C++ OpenCV?

I want to read the different number of video with respective of frames per second.

It has to work on all Video formats? .Avi, .MP4, .Flv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy (just take with a grain of salt, see remarks below):

```
VideoCapture cap("ma.avi");
double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

Comment: Notice that it won't work with all video formats though.

Comment: ... or on all machines even. yes. thanks, @KeillRandor

Comment: then How about .mp4 and .flv files ??

Comment: It is important to note, than many containers and protocols support variable frame rate (including mp4 and flv), and hence framerate should rarely be used/trusted.